# is there a way to allow URL in Azure firewall as https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/. We do not want to allow full Domain

Tags: azure, url, filter, firewall

Is there a way to allow URL in Azure firewall as https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/. We do not want to allow full Domain.

we do not want to allow full domain and want to allow specific URL only

Comment: I can allow the FQDN like  "cyberciti.biz" , but we do not want to allow the whole Domain. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way around this unless the TLS inspection is set on for the Azure firewall. You have to allow the whole domain only.

Poor design on Azure side

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).